# What parts of a physics undergraduate curriculum have been discovered since 1966?

Tags: soft-question, education, history

What parts of an undergraduate curriculum in fundamental physics have been discovered since, say, 1966? (I'm choosing this because it's 50 years ago.)

Physics textbooks have moved on since 1966 (though even quantum mechanics was already in textbooks in a form pretty close to the present, as e.g. Landau and Lifshitz was in its second edition in 1965). However, a strong case can be made that a large fraction of the material that has been included after 1966 was discovered before that - i.e. that the physics textbooks have simply been catching up to the state of research in the 60s.

(As an example, the Standard Model of electroweak interactions took on its modern form in 1967, and QCD, which is rarely studied in detail in undergraduate courses, followed shortly afterwards.)

I would like to disallow applications. I'm much more interested in finding out what (if any) fundamental shifts there have been in physics at the undergraduate level.

One reason I am asking is my suspicion is that there is very little or nothing which physics undergraduates learn which has been discovered since the 1960s, or even possibly earlier. Am I wrong?

<sup>This question is based on a [similar one on Math Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1082010/).</sup>

Comment: Depends on the course, certainly the one I am on we learn about e.g. lasers (invented in the 1960s), and current research techniques e.g. atomic force microscopy (1980s). Although granted the foundational stuff em, quantum, thermo tends to be older.

Comment: can't think of anything off-hand, but note that many important contributions to the standard models of particle physics and cosmology are younger than that (eg we only learned about the accelerated expansion of the universe in 1998)

Comment: This question (v1) seems like a list question.

Comment: Here are a couple of rather important discoveries: 1. heterojunction transistors https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heterojunction_bipolar_transistor   and 2. magnetic resonance *imaging* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_resonance_imaging

Comment: @hyportnex - I wonder whether *hetero-junction transistors* and *magnetic resonance imaging* are ever mentioned in any physics undergraduate curriculum or even explained.

Comment: @freecharly heterojunction transistors are standard stuff in RF engineering courses, and MRI is also mentioned along with other imaging procedures in signal processing courses. Oh wait, the question was what physics (and not engineering) undergraduates are learning.... sorry.

Comment: In the field of thermo electricity (Peltier elements etc.) the phenomenon was not really well described until during the 70's. And now a days materials and structures for that purpose are being discovered as late as within the past 5 years.

Answer (score 5):

- I think the biggest theoretical discovery would be [Jefimenko's equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jefimenko%27s_equations) (which just barely meet your cutoff) - the general solution to Maxwell's equations in terms of physically measurable quantities.  They're covered in Griffiths' E&M.
- The basic idea behind the experimental observation of [gravitationally induced quantum interference](http://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.34.1472) (technically a "quantum gravity" effect!) is actually a rather nice simple exercise in basic QM and might well be sketched out in an undergrad course.
- Bell’s theorem and Aspect's [Bell Test experiments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_test_experiments) ruling out the possibility of local hidden-variable explanations of QM (up to a few loopholes, most of which have now been ruled out).
- Any undergrad particle physics course would cover quarks, the gauge bosons other than the photon, the tau neutrino, and of course the Higgs boson, [all of which were discovered experimentally](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_particle_discoveries) after 1966. It would probably also mention neutrino masses, which were discovered in 1998-2001.
- *Lots* of stuff in astronomy, like exoplanets and dark matter (possibly even in a high school course!).  Any undergrad cosmology course would mention the 1998 discovery of dark energy and the acceleration of the universe's expansion.
- An undergrad course on general relativity would probably at least mention the [Kerr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerr_metric) and [Kerr-Newman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerr%E2%80%93Newman_metric) metrics describing rotating black holes, whose discoveries just *barely* lie outside your window.

Comment: Do  Jefimenko's equations meet the cutoff? "Jefimenko's equations seem to appear first in 1962 in the second edition of Panofsky and Phillips's classic textbook." (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jefimenko%27s_equations)

Comment: @akhmeteli Good point, I was looking at the date of Jefimenko's textbook.  Don't think the OP meant 50 years to be a hard cutoff anyway.

Comment: If I recall correctly, Zangwill's book traces Jefimenko's equations to around the 1910s, although I think they didn't have their exact current form back then.

Comment: Just checked Zangwill's book: in section 20.3 he attributes the formulae to G. A. Schott in 1912 and mentions that he derived them in the frequency domain. The reference is G.A. Schott, *Electromagnetic Radiation* (Cambridge University Press, Cambridge, 1912).

Comment: @NickolasAlves Interesting, thanks, I don’t know that history. I suspect that a frequency-domain version of Jefimenko’s equations probably wouldn’t have made it into an undergrad curriculum since it’s a bit more abstract, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Depends on the course, but certainly some of my undergraduate courses covered some modern things:

- My undergrad QM courses briefly touched on Berry's phase (it's a toss up whether you want to call this recent enough I guess)
- I had a computational physics course, which of course discussed algorithms invented since then. I guess you probably don't want to count this.
- My advanced classical mecahnics course discussed a bit about chaos, which I think narrowly meets your cutoff
- I had two undergrad condensed matter classes (one "traditional", one "soft"), which definitely discussed things more recent than your cutoff (for instance, polymer physics stuff worked out in the 70's) If you want to call this applied I will be disappointed.
- I had a biophysics class which definitely discussed more modern things, but all of the "physics" was older I guess, so I would totally understand not counting this.
- A little bit of cosmology in GR (again, would you call this applied? I guess maybe.)

And of course several courses, including the above ones, at least mentioned experimental techniques invented more recently than your cutoff, and experimental results from since your cutoff.

Of course, you're certainly right that most of the fundamentals which one discusses in undergrad courses are older than that.

Note also that this isn't necessarily only a modern phenomenon, it's just the case that it takes a while for more modern things to end up in curricula. I think I recall reading that even as a PhD student, Einstein did not have a course on Maxwell's theory of electromagnetism.

Comment: Kerr–Newman metric was discovered just in 1965, but wasn't well understood (MTW's Gravitation from 1973  have very short discussion on the subject)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe high-temperature superconductivity?

Comment: Yes, among so many other things. The question is extremely silly since it's a copy of my question on another stackexchange which makes no sense when asked about physics.

Comment: @Suzu Hirose: The Pak's question plagiarizes your question, and that is certainly wrong, but I would not call the question silly. I am not sure it is easy to find "many other things" satisfying the constraints of the question. I would be interested to see your answer.